# Extra Tabs in IMAP HTML Text

Tags: python, html, imap, mime, imaplib

I'm using Python and imaplib to obtain emails from a IMAP server (supports all kinds of IMAP servers - GMail, etc.).

My problem is: Using the IMAP BODY[INDEX] command to fetch a specific body part, the HTML comes with extra tabs. As in:

```
(...)</a>\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a>(...)
```

When showing the HTML the tabs are obviously extra:

[image]

(The screenshot is in the Portuguese language but I believe that is not relevant.

I have searched IMAP documentation but found nothing that helps. I am guessing these \t are always following tag closes (such as \t\t\t\t\t), so I could just find all tabs that come after a tag close and delete them, but I don't know if that would be a reliable method at all.

Thank you

Comment: Please show us the code processing the text in question.

Comment: Tabs are not significant to an html parser. They're probably in the source document. Html collapses all adjacent whitespace, including tabs to one space.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (for the time being at least).

When receiving data from a IMAP call response, there are \\r\\n characters delimiting the lines. I remove these.

However, I discovered that besides these there are also \\t characters coupled with these in some instances. For example:

\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\t

If I remove the \\t together with the \\r\\n, the HTML is presented perfectly.